# Can you declare a variable in ASP classic like this?

Tags: asp-classic, variables, heredoc

I am trying to see if this can be done in classic ASP:

```
Dim myVar
myVar = <<< END
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<BODY>
END
```

I can do this in PHP, but I am not positivte if it can be done in ASP.
Problem is I need to handle the HTML output via a variable, and I don't want to go through the HTML and convert `"` to `""`

**EDIT:**

I've found that this is called HEREDOC syntax in PHP.

Since its been asked, what I am trying to do is store HTML type tags (which may contain ', " characters which would otherwise break
`myVar = "<stuff color="red">here</stuff>"`

so I would need to fix it by replacing `color="red"` with `color=""red""`

**PART OF THE PROBLEM:**

I don't want to have to replace `"` with `""` for the content as I assign it, I guess a HEREDOC syntax is not available for ASP classic.

**OK FINE... :P**

Since everyone is asking me WHY I am going about it this way, here is why, I have to support this old ASP code, I don't want to, but suddenly the scope of this old app changes that they want the contents (which used to be an HTML page) to be emailed, SO... I wanted to HEREDOC the HTML output, pass it to the mail function and have it email.  Having said that, I know its sloppy, and I know it works better the other way, however this is what the job called for, I didn't want to re-write it, I just wanted to augment the output from HTML to HTML-EMAIL...

Hope that makes more sense ;)

Comment: It sounds like you're going about things backwards - you're trying to insert html content into an asp page. Classic asp really works better if you insert asp content into an html page.

Comment: updated my question to reflect the `WHY` of this question.

Comment: I have a use case for this as well: trying to incorporate page-specific JavaScripts into a template. It would be very handy to say `varJS = <entire script>`  Too bad ASP can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One language's syntax isn't going to work in a different language. You can, however, assign a string literal to the variable:

```
Dim myVar
myVar = _
    "<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" lang=""en"" xml:lang=""en"">" & vbCrLf & _
    "<head>" & vbCrLf & _
    "    <title>test</title>" & vbCrLf & _
    "</head>" & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "<BODY>" & vbCrLf
```

Comment: I know about this, BUT, as you noted, I still have to search and replace `"` to `""` in the <html> tags.. :(

Comment: I don't remember if vbCrLf is predefined in class ASP or not. If not, it's "vbCrLf = chr(13) & chr(10)".

Comment: That's why you get paid the big bucks.

Comment: @Dewayne: you can use either vbCrLf or vbNewLine - the latter is preferred as it will send either vbCrLf or vbCr as appropriate for the client.

Comment: chose Dewayne's answer as the final solution, even tho it was not what I wanted, as my end result was going through and search & replacing single `"` with double `""` so that they would not break the variable value. And @Dweayne, I wish I made the big bucks... :(

Comment: "One language's syntax isn't going to work in a different language"  That pretty much goes without saying; but it's not unreasonable to ask if one language has an **effective equivalent** to another language's syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do would be to keep the HTML in a separate file, and then open that file using a TextStream object, reading the string into a variable.

Comment: I thought about that, but how would I handle sections where I loop through a resultset of data? Unfortunetly this is age old asp classic that I need to fix up.

Comment: You could load in multiple fragments from disk.  There would be a header fragment (from <HTML> to the top of your <TABLE> or whatever), a row fragment, and then your footer fragment (from </TABLE> to the </HTML> tag.

Having said that, I would be very interested to know what kind of code requires this kind of convoluted syntax.  Why can't you include the HTML in the ASP file?  My suggestion would certainly be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do exactly what you're asking here. 
It might help, however, if you explained what you're trying to do. There may be some other way.

update:

You could consider putting your HTML fragments into seperate files. This would allow you to define them without having to do any reformatting of the HTML. In a similar manner you could put them into a database or even into resource files.

I'm still not 100% clear why you want these HTML fragments defined as variables, but these approaches would work.

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to store 'something' in a variable without fixing the `"` or any other character that might break the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

there is no herodoc for asp :) gogo escape - its the only useable way

Comment: Please expand this answer, as it makes little sense.